# Sharing a Finished Work Online

Tags: creative-writing, self-publishing

So I'm planning on getting back into writing soon and, for the first time, sharing it online. I have a few social media accounts where I plan on sharing it too. What would be the easiest way to share said work to multiple platforms? I would assume having hosted in one place and linking to it, which then brings me to ask: where should I host it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can post a link to your blog or directly to the story itself on the popular social network where you have the most subscribers. Often this is Instagram or Facebook. Use stories, fill in the tape. This works best

Comment: Thanks for the response. Guess it's time to brush up my web dev skills!